# Property map does not exist on type Observable when trying to convert a Array from plucked result

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, rxjs

Trying to sucessfully filter from objects using pluck and then converting the result to floating points using the numbers function()

please see the code below

Snippet of response from backend (much larger than this)

```
[ { devSn: '10000511',
   height: '178',
   age: '46',
   userId: '3',
   weight: '55.9',
   measureDate: '""2016-11-07T02:41:18.000Z""',
   __v: 0 },
 { devSn: '10000511',
   height: '179',
   age: '0',
   userId: '3',
   weight: '57.2',
   measureDate: '""2016-11-09T15:39:57.000Z""',
   __v: 0 } ]
```

Relevant Imports:

```
import { pluck } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'; // (shows map not being utilized for some reason, have already installed rxjs compact) 
import { from } from 'rxjs';
```

Code

```
    this.weightdevicesService.getweightdevicesbypatient(this.userId)
      .subscribe((weightdevices: Weightdevices[]) => {
        this.weightdevices = weightdevices;
      });
    console.log(this.weightdevices);
    const source = from(this.weightdevices); //changes to observable 
    const hfilter = source.pipe(pluck('height')); // pluck to filter out data to [ '55.9', '57.2' ]
    console.log(hfilter);
    const hfilterob = from(hfilter);  // ensures it is observable - this dosent seem to make a difference?
    const weightdata = hfilter.map(Number); // convert  [ '55.9', '57.2' ] to  [ 55.9, 57.2 ]
    console.log(weightdata);
```

After getting the response from the backend, I attempted to use the pluck() function to filter the data to [ '55.9', '57.2' ]. Then using the .map , I tried to convert them to [ 55.9, 57.2 ].

This results in the error
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}>'. I don't understand in this case

Comment: `hfilter.pipe(map(Number))` - prototype-patching operators were removed in v6 - https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-convert-to-pipe-syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @cartant I took a look back and realized my initial code was not necessary  , I have implemented a solution by finding out the command "forEach" and "push":

Initialize a empty array 
'''
weightdata = [];
'''

later on under

```
this.weightdevicesService.getweightdevicesbypatient(this.userId)
  .subscribe((weightdevices: Weightdevices[]) => {
    weightdevices.forEach (weightdevices => {
      this.weightdata.push(weightdevices.weight);
    });
    console.log(this.weightdata );
```

this.weight data results in [ 55.9, 57.2 ]